# What is the best Python library for 3D game development?

Tags: python, 3d

- Pygame and Pyglet are for 2D game development.
- Pysoy needs many requirements to be installed.
- I can't figure out how to install Pyogre.
- Panda3d is giving me this error and don't know how to fix it.

> importerror no module named direct.showbase.showbase

Is there any other good 3D game development library that could be installed on Windows XP with Python 2.7?  I prefer to install it using `pypm` or `pypi` to avoid possible errors that I'm currently having with Panda3d.

Comment: The problem is that most of the modules are going to have to build interfaces to libraries/engines like Panda and Ogre, or you need to use special versions. Look at [Panda's Download Page](http://www.panda3d.org/download.php?platform=windows&version=1.7.2&sdk), their installer for Windows includes a special Python that is pre-configured to work with Panda.

Comment: @birryree i have panda 1.7.2, i see that error, on the forum they say if you want to fix it, you have to use python 2.6.5 or copy a file called python.ph to python directory or add panda 3d to environment variables...I want to use python 2.7, i can't find any file called python.ph anywhere and C:\Panda3D-1.7.2\bin\ is already added to the path, i can't figure out what to do!!

Comment: i have many libraries installed with python 2.7 i can't use python 2.6.5 just for panda...

Comment: Unfortunately Panda requires Python 2.6.5, there is no guarantee that mixing modules between versions will work. You can explicitly set your own `PYTHONPATH` to test, it might work. In your command line you can do `set PYTHONPATH=C:\Panda3D-1.7.3\lib` (or whatever it is that has the python library. I don't use windows so that's the extent of my ability to help without knowing the specific directories in Panda3D's windows install. Supposedly the `.pth` file should be in  `C:\Panda3D-1.7.2\python\Lib\site-packages\panda3d.pth`.

Comment: `set PYTHONPATH=C:\Panda3D-1.7.3\lib` and then `ppython file.py`worked!! thank you is there a faster way to do it? if not I'll create a bath file

Comment: You can set it permanently in your environment. It's easiest to download [RapidEE](http://www.rapidee.com/) (careful it tries to install some piece of junk as part of the install, but the software itself is fine), and then set the `PYTHONPATH` variable as part of your environment permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pyopengl.
i think you might have to install pygame...